# Why do I see a bunch of requests to https://clouddebugger.googleapis.com:443 GET /v2/controller/debuggees/gcp*/breakpoints?agentId=* in logging?

Tags: google-cloud-debugger

We don't have any humans actively debugging our application, yet I see a bunch of requests in our logs to clouddebugger.googleapis.com (or from?).

Anyone know where and why these requests are coming in?

The requests take the following form:

`https://clouddebugger.googleapis.com:443 GET /v2/controller/debuggees/gcp*/breakpoints?agentId=*`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like these request are coming from GCP's [Cloud Debugger API](https://cloud.google.com/debugger/api); More specifically, the REST API using the Method: "[debugger.debuggees.breakpoints.get](https://cloud.google.com/debugger/api/reference/rest/v2/debugger.debuggees.breakpoints/get)" which is used for getting breakpoint information.

It could be that your application that is running (or using) the API to get your codes  breakpoint information and send it to Cloud Debugger. I would suggest reviewing your applications code to see if this API is being used anywhere in your application.